# Alloy mapping relations

Tags: verification, alloy

I am pretty much starting to look into alloy for doing some verification. I am trying to practice into making something for represent programming languages simple structure.

> An mapping entity has a program and dependency relations
>
> A program has functions
>
> Functions have lines of code
>
> Dependency relations is an entity that maps 2 lines of code in some function in the program between each other

Here is what I tried to do but the output graph shows a line of code that is linked to a  dependency tuple but not matched to the function. I need all lines of code to be in a function and they can be in dependencies or not...

```
abstract sig mapping{}

sig Dependency extends mapping {dep0,dep1: one line}

one sig Program extends mapping{ F: some function, D: some Dependency }

//mapping entity is composed of Dependency pairs 2 lines of code 
//and one program which has functions and dependency pairs

sig function { Line : some line}
//Function is made of line of code

abstract sig line{}

run {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add some facts that will enforce the constraints you have in mind for your model.

For example, to enforce that every line has a corresponding function, you can write something like

```
fact LinesBelongToFunctions {
  all ln: line | 
    one f: function | 
      ln in f.Line
}
```

This fact says that for each line `ln` there exists exactly one function `f` such that `f.Lines` contains line `ln`.